# How do I check when a listitem is selected and then do something if it is?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

I have the following code:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Celsius to Farenheit")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Farenheit to Celsius")

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ' Get the currently selected item in the list box. 
    Dim currentItem As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()

    ' Get the currently selected index of the item in the list box.
    Dim currentIndex As Integer = ListBox1.FindString(currentItem)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click ' calculate button
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a temperature to convert!")
    ElseIf currentItem = "Celsius to Farenheit" Then
        'do celsius to farenheit conversion
    ElseIf currentItem = "Farenheit to Celsius" Then
        'do farenheit to celsius conversion
    Else
        MsgBox("Please select a conversion first!")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

I am trying to check so that if a specific selection is made in ListBox1, then it performs that specific conversion when Button1 is clicked. However the above code cannot throws the error "currentItem is not declared.It may be inaccessible to its protection level". I suspect this has something to do with the

```
ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged
```

being a private sub, however changing it to public does not seem to have any affect.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Your problem is that `ListBox1.SelectedItems(0)` returns a `String`, not a `ListItem` or any kind of object like that; thus `String` does not have a `Selected` property or method. If you post your code for populating the list box (`ListBox1`), then I will be able to provide more assistance.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my original post with my code for populating the list box. How would I go about changing my code so that when a item is selected on ListBox1 it passes the index of the item on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to capture the index of the selected list box item when it is changed by the user:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
   ' Get the currently selected item in the list box. 
   Dim currentItem As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()

   ' Get the currently selected index of the item in the list box.
   Dim currentIndex As Integer = ListBox1.FindString(currentItem)
End Sub
```

Note: To wire up the event automatically, double click on the list box in the form designer and it should automatically generate the `Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged` stubbed method.

UPDATE:

To use the values gathered in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, you have to declare those variables at the class level (`Form1`), here is the code for that:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim currentItem As String
    Dim currentIndex As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Celsius to Farenheit")
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Farenheit to Celsius")
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        ' Get the currently selected item in the list box. 
        currentItem = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()

        ' Get the currently selected index of the item in the list box.
        currentIndex = ListBox1.FindString(currentItem)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click ' calculate button
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then
            MsgBox("Please enter a temperature to convert!")
        ElseIf currentItem = "Celsius to Farenheit" Then
            ' do celsius to farenheit conversion
        ElseIf currentItem = "Farenheit to Celsius" Then
            'do farenheit to celsius conversion
        Else
            MsgBox("Please select a conversion first!")
        End If
   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I have edited my original post, the problem now seems to be with those variables not being usable in the Button1_Click sub.

Comment: Yes, you need to move those variable up to the class level (`Form1`). See `UPDATE:` in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Karl Anderson, I have solved my problem using the following code.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim currentItem As String
Dim currentIndex As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Celsius to Farenheit")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Farenheit to Celsius")

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ' Get the currently selected item in the list box. 
    currentItem = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()

    ' Get the currently selected index of the item in the list box.
   currentIndex = ListBox1.FindString(currentItem)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click ' calculate button
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a temperature to convert!")
    ElseIf currentIndex = 0 Then
        Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text & " Celsius = " & (TextBox1.Text * 1.8) + 32 & " Farenheit"
    ElseIf currentIndex = 1 Then
        Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text & " Farenheit = " & (TextBox1.Text - 32) / 1.8 & " Celsius"
    Else
        MsgBox("Please select a conversion first!")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```